# How do I find references to maptools, rgdal, or rgeos, in my R-package? sf is the only spatial analysis package in the namespace

Tags: r, r-sf, rgdal, r-maptools

In my R package I replaced calls to other spatial analysis packages with sf functions, but still get a message: "The legacy packages maptools, rgdal, and rgeos, underpinning this package will retire shortly. Please refer to R-spatial evolution reports on https://r-spatial.org/r/2023/05/15/evolution4.html for details.
This package is now running under evolution status 0"
I cannot find any references to these packages in my code.

I expected that replacing all sp:: or maptools:: functions with sf:: functions would stop the warning appearing, but this did not happen.

The package is at: https://github.com/ThomasASmith/CRTspat/   The DESCRIPTION file has been updated several times (n.b. I should have written in the title that "sf is the only spatial analysis package in the DESCRIPTION")

Comment: Do you have a link to your package? 

- You could have a package that depend on maptools, rgdals and rgeos.
- Maybe some of your packages dep are not up to date and the version still depend on them
- Did you update the DESCRIPTION file? (and pkg version, and load the new version)

Comment: I just remotes::install_github("ThomasASmith/CRTspat"); library(CRTspat) and did not get any warning/message. Did you use `devtools::load_all()` workflow?

Comment: I could get rid of the message by removing the sp package from my system, but this crashes the tests. I now realize the problem is with the R-INLA package, which uses sp. I guess there is no solution until R-INLA remove this dependency.

Comment: Glad you find it! And yes I should have remember INLA is using sp (from a quick glance just for mesh). This issue make me also think that https://github.com/hrue/r-inla/issues/70 it should be solved if you update your `sp`

Comment: Many thanks @defuneste , I think this may have solved it